# How to get some bus_stations close to my location using osmdroid NominatimPOIProvider

Tags: android, osmdroid

I'm trying to get some `Bus_station` close to my location using osmdroid `NominatimPOIProvider`, but I receive the following `NullException`:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: south must be in
>   [-85.05112877980658,85.05112877980658]
>           at org.osmdroid.util.BoundingBox.set(BoundingBox.java:69).

I'm sure that coordinates don't any points close to my location

so this is my method where i implement the logic

```
 public  void poinOfInt(View view){

     bus_stop = myLocationNewOverlay.getMyLocation();

       NominatimPOIProvider poiProvider = new NominatimPOIProvider( BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
       ArrayList<POI> pois = poiProvider.getPOICloseTo(bus_stop, "highway", 50, 100);


      FolderOverlay poiMarkers = new FolderOverlay();
      map.getOverlays().add(poiMarkers);

      Drawable poiIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_default);
      for (POI poi:pois){
          Marker poiMarker = new Marker(map);
          poiMarker.setTitle(poi.mType);
          poiMarker.setSnippet(poi.mDescription);
          poiMarker.setPosition(poi.mLocation);
          poiMarker.setIcon(poiIcon);
         /* if (poi.mThumbnail != null){
            poiItem.setImage(new BitmapDrawable(poi.mThumbnail));
          }*/
         poiMarkers.add(poiMarker);
      }
    }
```

I receive the following error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.xibomba, PID: 6617
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4754)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19605)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5752)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4754) 
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19605) 
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5752) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: south must be in [-85.05112877980658,85.05112877980658]
>           at org.osmdroid.util.BoundingBox.set(BoundingBox.java:69)
>           at org.osmdroid.util.BoundingBox.(BoundingBox.java:43)
>           at org.osmdroid.bonuspack.location.NominatimPOIProvider.getUrlCloseTo(NominatimPOIProvider.java:73)
>           at org.osmdroid.bonuspack.location.NominatimPOIProvider.getPOICloseTo(NominatimPOIProvider.java:132)
>           at com.example.xibomba.MapaActivity.poinOfInt(MapaActivity.java:193)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4754) 
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19605) 
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5752) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Fixed formatting

Answer (score 1):

The last argument for the `poiProvider.getPOICloseTo` method is supposed to be in degrees (Documentation says: "maxDistance to the position, in degrees. Note that it is used to build a bounding box around the position, not a circle."). You passed `100` which is quite high value for degrees, so maybe you assumed those are kilometers or meters. Try smaller value, for example, `0.1`, `0.2` or something similar [as in examples](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_2).

Comment: it still not working. it gives the same NullException

Answer (score 0):

Provide the code setting the bus_stop geopoint.

(BTW, searching "highway" will not get bus stops)